# Python scraping by executing inpage Javascript

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can you please recommend some Library other than Selenium that could execute Javascript behind a button? The Reason I don't want Selenium since it opens a browser and I need to host script on remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selenium` + `PhantomJS`, you don't need to open a browser and it can execute javascript.

If you are opening a url with `selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS`, the javascripts will be executed like you are opening it in a normal browser.

Here is an example for click a button:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://exampelurl/')
driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys("user@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("Passwd").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()
```